# Не совсем очевидно, почему не проходит тест:

Tags: javascript

Уже поздно и всех глаза слипаются, но может кто найдёт в чём причина того, что тест проходит неуспешно, большое спасибо заранее!
Сам код:

```
class World {

 constructor() {

  }

  createPowerPlant() {
    let powerPlant = new PowerPlant();  

    return powerPlant;
  }

  createHousehold() { 
    let household = new Household(); 

    return household;
  }

  connectHouseholdToPowerPlant(household, powerPlant) {
    household.connecting(powerPlant.connectFromPowerPlant());
  }

  connectHouseholdToHousehold(household1, household2) {

  }

  disconnectHouseholdFromPowerPlant(household, powerPlant) {
    household.disconnect(powerPlant.disconectFromPowerPlant());
  }

  killPowerPlant(powerPlant) {

  }

  repairPowerPlant(powerPlant) {

  }

  householdHasEletricity(household) {
     return household.statusCheck();
  }     
}

class Household{
  constructor() {
    this.isConnectToPowerPlant = false;
  }

  connecting(connectStatus){
    this.isConnectToPowerPlant = connectStatus;
  }

  disconnect(disconectStatus){
    this.isConnectToPowerPlant = disconectStatus;
  }

  statusCheck(){
    return this.isConnectToPowerPlant;
  }      
}

class PowerPlant{
  constructor() {
    this.listOfKilledPlants = [];
    this.isActive = true;
  }  

  connectFromPowerPlant(){
    return true;
  }

  disconectFromPowerPlant(){
    return false;
  }
}
```

Тест:

```
const world = new World();

        const household1 = world.createHousehold();
        const household2 = world.createHousehold();

        const powerPlant1 = world.createPowerPlant();
        const powerPlant2 = world.createPowerPlant();

        world.connectHouseholdToPowerPlant(household1, powerPlant1);
        world.connectHouseholdToPowerPlant(household1, powerPlant2);
        world.connectHouseholdToPowerPlant(household2, powerPlant2);

        assert.equal(world.householdHasEletricity(household1), true);
        assert.equal(world.householdHasEletricity(household2), true);

        world.killPowerPlant(powerPlant2);
        assert.equal(world.householdHasEletricity(household1), true);
        assert.equal(world.householdHasEletricity(household2), false);

        world.killPowerPlant(powerPlant1);
        assert.equal(world.householdHasEletricity(household1), false);
        assert.equal(world.householdHasEletricity(household2), false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По какой причине результат вызова

```
world.householdHasEletricity(household2)
```

должен измениться после вызова

```
world.killPowerPlant(powerPlant2)
```

, если `killPowerPlant` ничего не делает, а `disconnectHouseholdFromPowerPlant` не вызывался?

Я уже писал Вам, что в Ваших классах не хватает связей между жилищами и электростанциями.

Можно сделать двустороннее знание: у `Household` будет ссылка на `PowerPlant`, а у `PowerPlant` будет массив `Household`-ов. Можно сделать отдельный объект (`Network`), хранящий список объектов, в каждом из которых - ссылка на `PowerPlant` и список подсоединенных к нему `Household`-ов.

Comment: Какого рода связь необходима? 
Если что-то глобальное - то хотя бы пните в нужную сторону

Comment: @HegoJune добавил